# Devise + CanCan + Different Models (roles)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

Good Afternoon All,

I'm just trying to think the best way to set this up at the beginning rather than changing everything at the end.

I have 3 models. I have a devise generated model called User.rb a model called employer.rb and candidate.rb.

My understanding is that once the user signs up and selects a role I can assign a role type after sign up and redirect them to a page on role where they can fill in the fields.

Each model has different fields and different data requirements.

How would I go about this, any pointers or ideas of how I'd approach this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a job for STI (single table inheritance)! Add a type column to your User model, and have the Employer and Candidate models inherit from User. There are a lot of STI with rails references out on the internet, but [here's one](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) specific blog post.

Comment: Yeah this is what I have been looking at. If I inherit from the user I only get the fields available in user.rb but not the fields available in employer.rb when I do employer.new

Comment: Right, you would add the employer-specific columns to the employer model.

Comment: I have different fields in the employer.rb but it returns only the user.rb columns

Comment: STI will inherit from the parent in this case user.rb but I need the user depending on the role to be able to update the columns in employer.rb

Comment: I got fed up just push all the fields into user and went with STI